# Comparing the excel cell value while importing in spring

Tags: html, regex, excel, spring, struts

I am importing excel data using html, spring and apache POI API. I need to do some validations before saving the data.
For a cell, I need to check whether its value is greater than 01 and less than 32.
I have seen like

`cell.getStringCellValue().matches(regex);`

Using this I have reached in a solution like this

`if(cell.getStringCellValue().matches("\b([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\b"))`

But I have read like, using regExp for comparing numbers is not such a good Idea, it is mainly for strings.

So my question is , is there a better way to solve my problem, finding whether the cell value falls within a range.

Comment: for `01`,`02`... your regex would be `\b(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\b`

Comment: Just taking a step back here, if your only testing that it's between a range what about this: `if(cell.getStringCellValue()>1 && cell.getStringCellValue()<32)` with a possible error check incase cell doesn't have a value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `0` before `[1-9]` inorder to match the number range from `01` to `09`.

```
\b(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\b
```

Comment: Yeah I get it. But my question is **is there a better way to solve my problem, finding whether the cell value falls within a range.**

Comment: so you don't want a regex solution.

Comment: I woudnt mind. But as I specified in the question regex wouldnt be be good solution as I am dealing with number here. If there is not any other solution I would go with regex only